# Error While Working on HI charts Export Server in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, charts, server, export

An error occured when rendering the chart: SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0 or uncaughtException: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined

I want to generate chart without having this error